# How to label Positive and negative x-axis using set_xlabel?

Tags: python, matplotlib

In the following code I have created 4 axis. Positive and negative x and y axis. I want to label positive x-axis as c1,negative x-axis as c2, positive y-axis as h1 and negative y-axis as h2. If I use ax.set_xlabel it will label whole x-axis. But I want to assign different labels to positive and negative x-axis. How can I do that?

```
`fig = plt.figure()
ax= fig.add_subplot(111)
x = [0.1,0.2,-0.2,0.3]
y=[0.3,-0.2,0.4,0.3]
ax.scatter(x,y)
ax.set_xlim([-0.5, 0.5])
ax.set_ylim([-0.5, 0.5])


ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `matplotlib.pyplot.text(x, y, s, fontdict=None, withdash=False, **kwargs)` to write text at a specified location on your graph. x and y correspond to the location of the string, s is the string.

Comment: In ax.text(0.21,-0.1,h1) labels positive x axis. What values should I assign to go on negative x-axis?

Comment: That is a symmetry around the Y axis, so you need to change the sign of x. Therefore, `ax.text(-0.21, 0.1, '')`.